# Can I give the partitions in my xen guests friendly names?

Tags: lvm, xen

I've got a bunch of LVM logical volumes on a machine running Xen, with descriptive names like "photos".

When I attach them to a Xen guest, the standard is to give them unmemorable names like xvda1, xvda2 etc, and this seems to be [encoded in block device numbers](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.2-testing/misc/vbd-interface.txt) so for example this doesn't work:

```
xm block-attach xenguest phy:/dev/vg_data/photos xvd-photos-1 w
```

giving the error

```
Error: Unable to find number for device (xvd-photos-1)
```

Is there any way I can get a friendly name presented to a Linux guest like I get on the dom0 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's about disk names (like your first harddisk in dom0 is called sda). You can't change this, AFAIK.